# Segmentation fault during apt-get install

Tags: linux, ssh, apt, segmentation-fault

`$ apt-get install openssh-server` fails with `Segmentation fault` when it attempts to generate keys.

This leaves me with a half-complete installation, but the binaries are in place.

I also notice that simple executing `sshd` or `ssh-keygen` also produces a `Segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `debsums` indicates that some files have different checksum from the files provided by the debian packages.

```
$ debsums -s
```

indicates that `libk5crypto.so.3.1` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` (and a few more) have status FAILED.

You will want to replace these files with files provided by the debian packages. To find out what package owns a file:

```
$ dpkg --search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
```

This tells us that this file is provided by `libk5crypto3`. (running the command with `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` tells us that it is provided by the `libssl1.0.0` package)

Then, simply reinstall the package(s):

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libk5crypto3 libssl1.0.0
```

Then, attempt to reinstall openssh:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge openssh-server
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```